# Problem Setting an HtmlSelect after pageload

Tags: c#, controls

I have a C# custom control that I am using to display an address form.  On the control, I have a select for picking your state.  On the pageload I set defaults for the select.  I have a public method exposed where I pass a variable to assign all the address information.

My problem is that the selects do not update to have the correct selected value when I run my method.  Any thoughts?

Below is the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

//Epicor Soap Stuff
using Clientele.Application.Client;
using Clientele.Application.Common;
using Clientele.Modules.Party.Common;
using Clientele.Modules.Party.Interface;

using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Data;

namespace AccountCenterUserControls.Address
{
    public partial class AddressFieldSet : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        //Credentials
        static String EpicorWSLogin = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EpicorWSLogin"].ToString();
        static String EpicorWSPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EpicorWSPassword"].ToString();
        static String EpicorWSDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EpicorWSDomain"].ToString();
        NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(EpicorWSLogin, EpicorWSPassword, EpicorWSDomain);

        private epicor_Organization.OrganizationFullDataSet.PhysicalAddressRow _Address;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load Address Data
            epicor_ValueListEntry.ValueListEntry ValueListEntryWS = new epicor_ValueListEntry.ValueListEntry();
            ValueListEntryWS.Credentials = myCredentials;

            region.DataSource = ValueListEntryWS.GetByListID(ValueListName.PhysicalAddressRegion).ValueListEntry.Select("", "Description ASC");
            region.DataTextField = "Description";
            region.DataValueField = "Entry";
            region.DataBind();

            country.DataSource = ValueListEntryWS.GetByListID(ValueListName.PhysicalAddressCountry).ValueListEntry;
            country.DataTextField = "Entry";
            country.DataValueField = "ValueListEntryID";
            country.DataBind();

            //Set some inteligent defaults for the state/country dropdown
            country.Value = Clientele.Modules.Party.Interface.Country.USA.ToString();
            region.Value = "MD";
        }

        public void Set(epicor_Organization.OrganizationFullDataSet.PhysicalAddressRow Address)
        {
            _Address = Address;

            address1.Value = Address["Address1"].ToString();
            address2.Value = Address["Address2"].ToString();
            address3.Value = Address["Address3"].ToString();
            city.Value = Address["City"].ToString();
            zip.Value = Address["PostalCode"].ToString();
            region.Value = Address["Region_"].ToString();
            country.Value = Address["CountryID"].ToString();
        }

        public epicor_Organization.OrganizationFullDataSet.PhysicalAddressRow Get()
        {
            _Address["Address1"]=address1.Value;
            _Address["Address2"]= address2.Value;
            _Address["Address3"]=address3.Value ;
            _Address["City"] = city.Value;
            _Address["PostalCode"] = zip.Value;
            _Address["Region"] = region.Value;
            _Address["CountryID"] = country.Value;

            return _Address;
        }

    }
}
```

From the parent controlI call the Set() function in it's Page_Load event.  All data except my selects get set correctly.

Is my problem that I cannot set the value of a select after the Page_Load event?  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out.  The Page_Load event is firing after my Set method.  I swapped out the Page_Load event for Page_Init and everything is all good.